# Different authentication method for different urls

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using spring-security (3.0.5.RELEASE) in my application. This application hosts an api and some restricted access for users, i would like to use spring-security to authenticate on both sides of the application.

- Api is on mydomain/api/*
- User restricted access is on mydomain/restricted/*

Api authentication must be done by a sort of api_key

User access authentication is done by a login form

The first question is : Is it possible?
If yes, how could i do it?  i've read a lot of things on the Internet, but i can't figure out how to do it (except by upgrading to spring 3.1 ...)

Any help is welcome ...

Regards

Comment: This is clearly feasible. I don't have enought time for a proper answer right now, but believe I've done much more complicated in the past. I might come back here to give a complete answer if nobody does. Meanwhile, 2 advices: you will find more information on the official documentation than on google, and reading the source code of spring security helps a lot.

Comment: Hi, as i don't really want to upgrade spring version, and stil can't figure out how to do this thing, i hope you'll have the time to give me the answer ... regards

Comment: Finally somebody gave the answer I had in mind. I agree on the fact that you should upgrade Spring. This should not be painful. If it is, it might be the right time to reconsider your build process ;=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading to Spring Security 3.1 is really the best way to do this cleanly.  If you can't do that you can still achieve the desired result but it's not going to be as pretty.  If your resources are cleanly separated in the URL space (as they appear to be) you can add a second Spring Security filter covering only the /api resources and make sure it applies before the default one.  To separate the configuration in Spring Security 3.0 you need a separate application context for your second filter, and configure the filter to find it in a well-known place - e.g. a DispatcherServlet creates a context and stores it in the servlet context in an attribute related to its name ("api" in the example below):

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>apiSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.api</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>apiSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

The dispatcher servlet in this example has an application context at `/WEB-INF/api-servlet.xml` which contains a Spring Security filter chain with `id="apiSecurityFilter"`.